# Combine Api data and room database Android

Tags: android, api, android-recyclerview, retrofit, android-room

[github link](https://github.com/PuruPanda1/Expense-Manager)

I am trying to create an Android application where I can want to kind of display crypto portfolio which contains: crypto name, symbol, current price, profit

Now, I have the crypto name, id, symbol, and buying price in the room database and I have the current price in API from coingecko which I can get using the crypto id.

The problem is how can I combine them in a recycler view?

I want to showcase crypto name, symbol from the room database, and current price from API and calculate the profit or loss.

Comment: If you are using flow , you can combine both the flows using flatMapLatest and get a single observable flow.

Comment: Can you share a guidr or something like that, I am using live data, how to use flapMap with live data?

Comment: Check this github if you can help me solve the error
https://github.com/PuruPanda1/Expense-Manager

Answer (score 0):

Using [RxJava](https://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html) you could get results and combine them:

```
  Observable.just(cryptoFromRoom)
  .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
  .flatMap({ crypto ->
    getPriceFromApi(cryptoId) //returns another Observable<ApiResult> after calling the API
  }, {
    //this is executed after resolving the last observable emitted, so the result is ready.
     id: Long, apiResult: ApiResult -> Pair(crypto , apiResult) 
  })
  .subscribe({ result ->
    result.first //crypto 
    result.second //apiResult
  })
```

Comment: I am using live data and viewModel. Is there any way i can use them and do the same thing as I dont know about RxJava.

Comment: Check this github if you can help me solve the error
https://github.com/PuruPanda1/Expense-Manager